# attempting to install new kernel, error modules.order & Makefile Error 2

Tags: sed, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel

Attempting to install a new kernel.
once it is compiled, I enter:

```
su -c "make modules_install install"
```

this error populates :

```
sed: can't read modules.order: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1304: _modinst_] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:327: __build_one_by_one] Error 2
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Check if the file is there. If it is not, modify file path.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `install`, and just run like `su -c "make modules_install"`

Answer (score 9):

I've had the same issue compiling Linux Kernel 5.6.14 on Debian 10.4 using config from my current working Linux Kernel 4.19.0 inside VirtualBox.

```
make oldconfig
make
make modules_install
```

gave me the same output. After commenting line **CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS** in config which I copied to Linux Kernel 5.6.14 source directory and repeating from the start **make** took much longer and then I was able to do **make modules_install**.

Found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293642/attempting-to-compile-kernel-yields-a-certification-error), don't know why it worked, sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: I just encountered same issue. `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS = ""` worked for me. And I found actually `make` failed. `make -s` only shows warnings & errors, and helps to show that there's an error.

Answer (score 3):

I just went thru the same thing. The problem appears to be the make commands used to build the kernel and modules. In the old days, you could just do "make bzImage" then a "make modules_install".  This current results in no modules. If you are building a newer kernel, you should do "make V=1 all" then a "make modules_install".  I think this streamlines the compiling of modules. It is the method recommended in the kernel admin-guide.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually because you did not compile the modules. Please try make -j `nproc` before `make modules_install` again.